# How to ensure iphone app crash logs can be symbolocated?

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash

I have a niggling issue in an app I'm developing; it's not in the app store, however I can see the crash logs from the Organizer when I plug in my iPhone.

The problem is that the crash logs do not symbolocate.  I can see a `.dSYM` file in my `build/Debug-iphoneos` directory from the last time I installed the app on my phone, however I can't figure out how to make it work.

I've consulted [this technote](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html), however it doesn't really say what to do, simply that the organizer "must have the .dSYM and application binary that produced the crash report."

How do I make it "have" these things?  They appear to be sitting around on my hard drive, but it doesn't recognize them.  Is there a more clear step-by-step process to making this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **Build And Archive** every time you're ready to send something out, you'll always have the dSYM file.

If you don't Build And Archive, you can instead right/control-click on your .app file in the **Products** group in Xcode and choose **Reveal In Finder**. The folder revealed will contain both the .app and the .app.dSYM files. You'll need to copy the .dSYM file somewhere else because it will be replaced on the next build.

Build And Archive is your better bet, as everything is taken care of for you.

Comment: Yup, I've always gotten into a habit of copying off my .dSYM file with every version of an app I submit to the App Store.

Comment: So does the organizer just magically find it if I copy it somewhere?  Or, how do I make sure it's findable by the organizer?

Comment: If you Build And Archive, it magically finds it. My experience with copying it somewhere was that it magically found it, but I don't recall exactly where I was putting it, something could well affect the magic.